# Laravel Excel import .csv line endings not recognized

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, laravel-excel

**I am trying to update a sql database table using the data of an excel file (.csv)** in Laravel using the [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) repository.
My Controller function gives back the content of the excel file, but just in an array of 2 (it should be 604).
**Therefore, I think I would have to add 'line ending \t' to my function.**
But I do not know how.

---

Here is what I know so far:
**The controller**

```
public function uploadExcel()
{
        Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'), function ($reader) {

        foreach ($reader->toArray() as $value) {
            $insert[] = [
            'member_title' => $value->member_title,
            'member_first_name' => $value->member_first_name,
            'member_name_affix' => $value->member_name_affix,
            'member_last_name' => $value->member_last_name,
            'member_private_address' => $value->member_private_address,
            'member_private_zip_code' => $value->member_private_zip_code,
            'member_private_location' => $value->member_private_location,
            'member_private_phone' => $value->member_private_phone,
            'member_private_mobile' => $value->member_private_mobile,
            'member_private_fax' => $value->member_private_fax,
            'member_private_mail' => $value->member_private_mail,
            'member_business_position' => $value->member_business_position,
            'member_business_name' => $value->member_business_name,
            'member_business_address' => $value->member_business_address,
            'member_business_zip_code' => $value->member_business_zip_code,
            'member_business_location' => $value->member_business_location,
            'member_business_area_code' => $value->member_business_area_code,
            'member_business_phone' => $value->member_business_phone,
            'member_business_fax' => $value->member_business_fax,
            'member_business_mobile' => $value->member_business_mobile,
            'member_business_mail' => $value->member_business_mail,
            'member_join_date' => $value->member_join_date,
            'extra' => $value->extra
            ];
        }
    });
    if(!empty($insert)) {
        die(var_dump($insert)); <-- puts out the array for testing
        DB::table('members')->insert($insert);
    }
    return redirect('index.index');
}
```

According to the [official documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) I would have to add this to my project to recognize the correct line endings:

```
class UserListImport extends \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ExcelFile {
    protected $lineEnding = '\t';
}
```

If my hunch is correct and this snippet from the documentation would solve my problem:
**Where do I have to create this file, which contains the code from the documentation?

 And do I have to change anything else to make that file take affect?**

---

I am really new to Laravel and I would be very thankful for any kind of help!!

---

**UPDATE**

---

**Error message**

> Class App\UserListImport contains 1 abstract method and must therefore
>   be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ExcelFile::getFile)

**app/UserListImport.php**

```
namespace App;

    class UserListImport extends \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ExcelFile {
    protected $lineEnding = '\t';

    public function loadExcel() {
        Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'), function ($reader) {

            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $value) {
                $insert[] = [
                'member_title' => $value->member_title,
                'member_first_name' => $value->member_first_name,
                'member_name_affix' => $value->member_name_affix,
                'member_last_name' => $value->member_last_name,
                'member_private_address' => $value->member_private_address,
                'member_private_zip_code' => $value->member_private_zip_code,
                'member_private_location' => $value->member_private_location,
                'member_private_phone' => $value->member_private_phone,
                'member_private_mobile' => $value->member_private_mobile,
                'member_private_fax' => $value->member_private_fax,
                'member_private_mail' => $value->member_private_mail,
                'member_business_position' => $value->member_business_position,
                'member_business_name' => $value->member_business_name,
                'member_business_address' => $value->member_business_address,
                'member_business_zip_code' => $value->member_business_zip_code,
                'member_business_location' => $value->member_business_location,
                'member_business_area_code' => $value->member_business_area_code,
                'member_business_phone' => $value->member_business_phone,
                'member_business_fax' => $value->member_business_fax,
                'member_business_mobile' => $value->member_business_mobile,
                'member_business_mail' => $value->member_business_mail,
                'member_join_date' => $value->member_join_date,
                'extra' => $value->extra
                ];
            }
        });
        if(!empty($insert)) {
            die(var_dump($insert));
            DB::table('members')->insert($insert);
        }
        return redirect('index.index');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\UserListImport;

public function uploadExcel()
{
    UserListImport::loadExcel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs assumed you created a new custom class extending `Excelfile`.

```
class UserListImport extends \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ExcelFile
```

means exacly this.

I usually prefer to add my own application namespaced folders for anything that my application needs.

It this case I would extract anything out from the controller and call my own class to process `Input::file('import_file')`. That class is the place where to put that attribute to overwrite how the library interacts with the file.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Let's say I create the UserListImport class under app/UserListImport.php. Then how exactly would I 'extract anything out from the controller' and call that class?

Comment: When you extend another class, your class inherits its methods. I suppose you may just need to add a custom method `nameItWhateverYouWant` method and call `$this->load()` inside it, otherwise `parent::load()`. That `load()` method behaves exacly like the `Excel::load()` you called in your controller. Not having the code under my nose I can't be sure, try and give us a feedback.

Comment: Remember to `use App\UserListImport;` at the top of your controller and call it like `UserListImport::theMethodNameYouChose()`. In `UserListImport` you have to namespace it at the top using `namespace App;`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! Now, I am getting this error: `Class App\UserListImport contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ExcelFile::getFile)`

Comment: No rush! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This `\t` means tabulation(gap between words). For line endings the following combinations of chars are used `'\n', '\r\n'`. It depends on the operating system. `'\n'` is for Unix/Linux/Mac OS and `'\r\n'` is for Windows families.

Comment: Thank you!! But how do I tell the laravel function to use '\t' as a line ending?

Comment: Why should you do it? @kringeltorte

Comment: Let's say I would like to tell the function that '\n' should be the line ending. How would I do that?